# How do I include gems in Rake files without specifying them in a Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rake

I am trying to write my first Rake file. It looks something like this:

lib\tasks\routes_check.rake:

```
require 'curb'
task :route_test do 
  puts "checking routes"
end
```

Running `rake route_test` fails with the message:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- curb
```

I ran it with `--trace` and the trace is [here](https://gist.github.com/gprasant/5290933).

I can't figure out why this does not work. In the same `lib/tasks` directory, I saved a .rb file which looks like:

task.rb:

```
require 'curb'

puts "Hello"
```

When I run this file with `ruby task.rb`, it works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails applications by default use Bundler, so you need to add `gem "curb"` to your Gemfile and then ”install” (register) the new gem to Rails bundle with `gem install`.

Comment: Hmmm, That worked. Is there anyway I can use this gem in my rake file without actually adding it to my Gemfile? I am not going to be using this gem anywhere else in my rails project.

Comment: You can group gems, and e.g. add a `:test` group. The gem will still be added to the project in general (e.g. if you do a `bundle install`), but you get to manage dependencies a little better.

Comment: also you can exclude for example test group with `bundle install --without test`

Comment: Also @gprasant, it’s because your rails comes from ”bundle”, you can’t easily use gems outside. Instead, often gems just fails because of conflicting versions, and then you use command like `bundle exec rake ..`.